# Flutter module added to android project overriding the android project's name with flutter module's name

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a multi-flavoured android app and I have flutter module that I have added into my android project as a sub module. When I see recent apps section I notice the correct name i.e. **UAT-app** of the project as mentioned in the label added in the manifest file of the android project.

```
<application
    android:name=".app.App"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
    android:label="UAT-app"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.myapp"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    tools:replace="android:icon,android:label,android:theme,android:name">
```

But whenever I open any flutter screen in the app and see the recent app section I notice that the name of app changed from **UAT-app** to **flutter-demo** as this name is mentioned in the flutter module as below code

[link to main.dart](https://pastebin.com/av0qky2c)

Help me to show android's project name as per the app flavour instead of flutter-demo in the recent app section.